# Why do I get a zero error in my prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

The code below is my first code and first approach to Titanic Kaggle contest. Something is wrong because my predictions have a zero `mean_absolute_error`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
y=df['Survived']
feature_columns = ['Pclass']
X = df[feature_columns]

# split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)


model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

#validation
val_mae = mean_absolute_error(predictions, y_test)
print("Validation MAE: {:,.0f}".format(val_mae))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column **df['Survived']** is a One-hot-encoded column, i.e. it contains only values of **[0,1]**, which means *the highest absolute error for a datapoint can go is 1* (i.e. if your model predicts 1 when it's 0 or vice versa; it's also worth noting individual absolute errors can only be either 0 or 1, since your y_true is either 0 or 1 and your predictions are either 0 or 1). So the *mean_absolute_error* will also lie between **0** and **1**, and you are rounding this value to the nearest whole number here `"Validation MAE: {:,.0f}".format(val_mae)`, so if it's <= 0.5, it will only show 0.

Several other points: this is a *classification problem*, you **should not be using mean_absolute_error** which is used in *regression problems*. Instead use confusion_matrix/classification_report. Also, mean_absolute_error takes in values as mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_predicted) thus in your code (if you were to use mean_absolute_error) it should look like mean_absolute_error(y_test, predictions).